# Round Robin DNS

Tags: dns

На работе потребовалось организовать балансировку нагрузки на два сервера с помощью dns. Концепция абсолютно прозрачна и понятна, но непонятно, как это сделать с технической точки зрения - насколько понимаю, А-запись может быть только одна, и среднестатистический регистратор не просто так не дает добавить вторую.

Времени читать спеки в данный момент нет, поэтому прошу на пальцах объяснить, что именно я должен сделать через регистратора.

Comment: Попробуйте создать две A-записи для одного и того же имени.

Comment: A записей может быть сколько угодно. собственно вам и надо создать вторую с другим ip. Если интерфейс регистратора не позволяет это сделать то уточните у них в техподдержке или уходите к другому регистратору или поднимайте DNS у себя

Comment: @kff текущий регистратор не предоставляет возможности, из-за чего я и полез проверять свои знания. Сейчас рассматриваем cloudflare в качестве решения.

Comment: @Mike, написали бы в формате ответа, я бы принял

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A` записей может быть сколько угодно. Для балансировки нагрузки надо именно добавить дополнительные записи с другими IP адресами. Если интерфейс регистратора не позволяет добавлять несколько записей уточните в техподдержке, действительно ли это так. Если не позволяет - меняйте регистратора или выносите DNS-сервера в другое место (поддержка DNS не обязательно должна быть на мощностях самого регистратора).